# Sort kube pods by memory/cpu per node

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a way to combine `kubectl top pod` and `kubectl top nodes`?

Basically I want to know pods sorted by cpu/memory usage **BY** node.

I can only get pods sorted by memory/cpu for whole cluster with `kubectl top pod` or directly memory/cpu usage per whole node with `kubectl top nodes`.

I have been checking the documentation but couldnt find the exact command.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak kube 1.18.18 and kubectl 1.16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in solution to achieve your expectations. `kubectl top pod` and `kubectl top node` are different commands and cannot be mixed each other. It is possible to [sort results](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#interacting-with-running-pods) from `kubectl top pod` command only by `cpu` or `memory`:

```sh
kubectl top pod POD_NAME --sort-by=cpu              # Show metrics for a given pod and sort it by 'cpu' or 'memory'
```

If you want to "combine" `kubectl top pod` and `kubectl top node` you need to write custom solution. For example script in Bash based on [this commands](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/).

Comment: Alright, thanks for the confirmation, I wanted to know if it was possible or not